# Proving whether $\{p(x) \in P(F) \mid p(0) + p'(0) = 0\}$ form a subspace

Tags: vector-spaces, solution-verification

I am trying to determine whether this subset of polynomials,
$$
\{p(x) \in P(F) \mid p(0) + p'(0) = 0\}
$$
forms a subspace. I believe that it does, but my attempt could be missing something. Here is what I've done so far. I'll call this set $U$ for convenience.

**Identity.** For the zero function, we have
$$
(0 + 0')(0) = 0(0) + 0'(0) = 0(0) + 0(0) = 0 + 0 = 0,
$$
so $0 \in U$.

**Closed under addition.** Let $f,g \in U$. Then
$$
f(0) + f'(0) = 0 \text{ and } g(0) + g'(0) = 0.
$$
It then follows that
$$
(f+g)(0) + (f+g)'(0) = f(0) + g(0) + f'(0) + g'(0) = (f(0) + f'(0)) + (g(0) + g'(0)) = 0 + 0 = 0,
$$
so $f+g \in U$.

**Closed under scalar multiplication.** Let $\alpha \in F$ and $f \in U$. Then
$$
(\alpha f)(0) + (\alpha f)'(0) = \alpha f(0) + \alpha f'(0) = \alpha (f(0) + f'(0)) = \alpha \cdot 0 = 0,
$$
so $\alpha f \in U$.

How does this look?

Comment: Looks good to me!

Comment: It is ok apart from 2 misprints:  $(g(0) + f'(0)) $ and
 $ (\alpha f')(0)$.

Comment: Looks ok. You could also try to show that for any homomorphism $\varphi:V\rightarrow W$, the kernel $ker(\varphi)$ forms a subvector space of $V$. Your example is then the special case $V=P(F), W=F$ and $\varphi(p)=p(0)+p'(0).$